# How to link kernel module to use their function?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I have some kernel module that i have added thanks modprobe:

```
sudo modprobe mymodule
```

In this module i have some function that i want to call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int f = my_foo();
    printf("%d", f);
    return 0;
}
```

How I need to link mymodule to make that work. Help please.

Comment: You cannot generally call arbitrary kernel internal functions from userspace.  Instead, you must go through some existing interface, such as creating a device, opening it, and using a custom ioctl() call on its file descriptor, or (more currently preferred) nodes in sysfs or procfs.  Kernel functions callable from userspace are called syscalls, and adding/modifying these is considering a quite major change, something that properly requires a re-compilation not simply a new module.

Comment: Is your module block or char device? How it registers itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. **Kernel modules aren't libraries**. What you're looking for seems to be static/dynamic   libraries.
Of course, you might want to implement a syscall, but is it really worth the trouble ? You'll need to recompile the kernel ...

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of documentation about how to write a kernel module. You can start [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html).

More documentation: [Linux Driver Development, Third edition](http://free-electrons.com/doc/books/ldd3.pdf).

Be very careful! A badly written kernel module can crash your kernel easily!